# Android - Layout gravity/width related problem

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I know I am doing a small mistake.

I am using LinearLayout and I want to place the "icon-image" at "Center". I am using the following code:

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" 
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


   <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0">
        
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/ImageView01" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center">
        </ImageView>
   </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout>
         ............
   </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

As you see above, I have also set `layout_gravity`.

Now my problem is, if I set `android:layout_width="wrap_context"` instead of "fill_parent" in Child Linear Layout (i.e. LinearLayout02) then it works fine. but then what should I do to set icon-image at Center while setting fill_parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to LinearLayout02 to specify that its contents should be centered horizontally:

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
```

Comment: thats make my life....i know i am doing silly mistake ..but however you catched me...thanx